# Is there a question for 'I've wiped my hard-drive installing, what do I do?' with good answers?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a ridiculous amount of questions (quite alot fairly low-quality) like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487923/i-lost-all-my-drive-while-installing-ubuntu-how-to-get-back-my-drives), or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152388/usb-drive-wiped-during-install), where the OP installed Ubuntu or something and lost their data, by not noticing all the warnings about disks being wiped, or by selecting the wrong thing to install to.

Is there a good question that these could be linked to? Most of the answers say *'use this program that won't work/is expensive'* - though [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483584/recover-data-from-formatted-lvm-luks-ext3-after-ubuntu-installed-over-it/486255#486255) one is OK. I know that the data is likely pretty much gone anyway (particularly if the disk is wiped by before formatting), but answers of higher quality could help. If you have just had half you life's work wiped by accident, you do sort of want it back....

Comment: There should be, it happens often enough.

Comment: I though that, thats why I asked.

Comment: I'm biased but I thought this one was good.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/463094#46309

Comment: The best thing would be to fix the relevant bug so users do not delete their partitions in the first place: [Launchpad bug #1265192 - 
Install/reinstall wipes out all/other partitions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192). Unfortunately that bug seems to have very low priority from the developer it is assigned to.

Comment: I have even sent a mail to the webmaster of Ubuntu asking them to add a "make a backup!" advice on the installation page. Never had any answer, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) seems like a contender.

There are quite a few good examples in the [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) tag.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) as well for data recovery tools.

Answer (score 1):

What bothers me about [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) one is that you have to read through the comments before you see a warning about reducing your chances of recovery by using the drive you are attempting to recover. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463076/partitions-disappeared-after-power-loss-while-installing/) one is better IMHO . Perhaps they could be merged.